# About csv data differences between PSI and GSC

Tags: google-search-console, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

I have a problem about cwv data in PSI and GSC. Hope specialists can help me with it.

I noticed that when i check a specific url in PSI, it has two versions: this url and origin. And according to the documentation, PSI data is based on real-user data for this URL. Does it mean that if a url has insufficient users, aka traffic (from seo or direct source), the shown cwv data will show the origin version, which will be the cwv data of the whole domain instead of this specific url?

In the same way, we assume that cwv data shown in the GSC are all based on urls with natural search traffic (search users). Don't know if we understand right.

So can we say that PSI cwv data is based on urls have different traffic sources including seo, direct and maybe social; and GSC cwv data is based on urls only have natural search traffic?

We want to know the difference cwv data sources, so our tech guy can decide which data can we use to check and therefore improve the cwv of whole site (have over 30M live listings). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both PSI and GSC are based on the same underlying data source: [Chrome UX Report](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/). All [eligible users'](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology/#user-eligibility) experiences are included in the dataset and there is no difference in the user population across PSI and GSC.

Comment: We understand that both PSI and GSC are based on the same underlying data source (real user data), but we want to know when gsc group urls to show cwv data, will it only check urls that have search traffic? 

This confused us a long time. Because we find that the number of our good urls are decreasing as search traffic increasing.But the actual number of our good urls are not changing.